# Triangular waveform to square waveform circuit

Tags: waveform

I am working on a frequency counter project and I am in the midst of thinking about how to go about doing a triangular wave to square wave converter. I have done some research but couldn't find any circuit diagram that could help. It was mostly just triangular wave to sine wave. I would appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks.

Comment: So I'm guessing the triangle-to-sine converter circuits you found were probably all integrators? What do you think you'd get if you fed a triangle into a differentiator?

Comment: Or a comparator?

Comment: The right answer depends a bit on whether you need it to work over a wide range of amplitudes and/or frequencies, and whether the triangle wave has noise on it that has to be rejected.

Comment: Differentiate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparator is used to produce square waves:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLsSl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At high frequencies (\$ > \frac{1}{2\pi R C}\$), the R-C filter passes only the DC offset of the input signal, and the output switches at the zero-crossings relative  to this level.

At low frequencies, the R-C filter simply produces a time lag and the output switches based on the slope of the input signal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would work, change the ratio of r2 to r3 to change the duty cycle

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPZYts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LM393 is a comparator, when the signal at the + input is greater the signal at the - input the output is pulled high via R1, when the signal at - is greater than the signal at + the output is driven low. The potential divider R2 and R3 defines the set point at which the transition from high to low happens.